# flutter ,My app dies whenever i enter the videoPlayerScreen

Tags: flutter, video

it's all good on android but not good on iOS.
whenever i try to enter the videoPlayerScreen
error occurs
I tryed another project with same class code ,
it was fine.
but in this project doens't work.

Here's my code

```
...
class _VideoTestState extends State<VideoTest> {
  final FijkPlayer player = FijkPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      player.setDataSource( // ✅ App dies in here
          'http://baishan.oversketch.com/2019/11/05/d07f2f1440e51b9680f4bcfe63b0ab67.MP4',
          autoPlay: true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Center(
          child: FijkView(
            player: player,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in Android studio when I enter it , it dies immediately, Log( Lost connection to device. )
but in Xcode show log like this.
[image]

I assume its package problem.
not sure about it but only difference between another project and this one is
another project has few package ( actually minimum packages to play video )
this one has alot include firebase things.

I tried ,
flutter clean ,
rm Podfile.lock
pod install.

is there any clue to solve this problem??